# How to count moves in BFS algorithm? (Shortest path in a maze)

Tags: c++, algorithm, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

So I try implementing a BFS algorithm and really understand how it works (creating some kind of "my version", out of scratch, just looking at graphs and some pseudocodes) and here is what I ended up with:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<queue>

using namespace std;



    void main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        // Deklaracja uchwytu do pliku (tylko do odczytu pliku)
        ifstream plik(argv[1]);
        // Tablica stringow - przechowujaca wartosci pol 12x12
        string labirynt[12];
        pair <int, int> start;
        pair <int, int> koniec;
        // Wektor par - działa jak tablica, przechowuje pary współrzędnych pól
        queue <pair<int, int>> kolejka;
        // Tablica odwiedzin - sprawdza czy pole zostalo odwiedzone, 0 jesli nie, 1 jesli tak
        bool odwiedzone[12][12] = { 0 };
        // Zmienna pomocnicza - bo getline sluzy do umieszczania danych w stringu, nie w tablicy znakow
        int i = 0;
        // Pętla wczytująca tekst z pliku do tablicy labirynt
        while (getline(plik, labirynt[i]))
        {
            i++;
        }

        // Wyszukanie początku i końca w labiryncie (A i B)
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
            {
                if (labirynt[i][j] == 'A')
                {
                    start.first = i;
                    start.second = j;
                }
                if (labirynt[i][j] == 'B')
                {
                    koniec.first = i;
                    koniec.second = j;
                }
            }

        }


        // Ustawiamy pole startowe jako odwiedzone - żadne pole nie może być odwiedzone więcej niż 1 raz
        odwiedzone[start.first][start.second] = true;



        // Wiersz i kolumna bieżącego wierzchołka
        int w, k;




        kolejka.push(start);

        // Dopóki kolejka nie jest pusta
        while (!kolejka.empty())
        {
            // Pobieramy z kolejki wiersz i kolumnę bieżącego wierzchołka
            w = kolejka.front().first;
            k = kolejka.front().second;
            // Usuwamy parę z kolejki
            kolejka.pop();


            // Sprawdzamy czy dotarliśmy do wyjścia
            if (w == koniec.first && k == koniec.second)
                break;

            // Przeglądamy sąsiadów bieżącego wierzchołka

            for (i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
            for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
            {

                if ((i != j) && (!i || !j))
                if (labirynt[w + i][k + j] == ' ' && !odwiedzone[w + i][k + j])
                {
                    odwiedzone[w + i][k + j] = true;
                    pair <int, int> para;
                    para.first = w + i;
                    para.second = k + j;
                    kolejka.push(para);
                    cout << kolejka.front().first << endl;
                    cout << kolejka.front().second << endl;
                }
            }



        }
    system("PAUSE");
    }
```

Here is the example maze I use (program reads from file that is dropped on .exe)

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxA  xxxxxxx
xx x  xxxxxx
x  x  xxxxxx
xx x    xxxx
xx xxx xxxxx
x   xxxxxxxx
x x  xxxxxxx
x xxx xxxxxx
x    xxxxxxx
xxx     Bxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

It works (shows coordinates of every field in a maze it goes through and finds B), but I don't know how to count moves needed to go through shortest path.

Comment: This related question may contain an algorithm useful to you http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/62315/31256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using `odwiedzone[w + i][k + j] = true;` for checking the coordinate have been stepped before, use something like `odwiedzone[w + i][k + j] = now + 1` to count the number of step from start to that position:

```
// first, declare all odwiedzone[][]=-1
...

odwiedzone[start.first][start.second] = 0;
// first position needs 0 step
...
            for (i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
            for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
            {

                if ((i != j) && (!i || !j))
                if (labirynt[w + i][k + j] == ' ' && odwiedzone[w + i][k + j]==-1)
                {
                    odwiedzone[w + i][k + j] = odwiedzone[w][k]+1;
                    //next position = now position + 1

                    pair <int, int> para;
                    para.first = w + i;
                    para.second = k + j;
                    kolejka.push(para);
                    cout << kolejka.front().first << endl;
                    cout << kolejka.front().second << endl;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Gonna try it. Shouldn't there be a odwiedzone[w + i][k + j] == -1? I guess there should.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 ways of achieving what you want:

1. Use a separate queue for storing the associated distance with each cell, e.g. start will have 0, each neighbour of start will have 1 and so on. Each time you add a new neighbor, his value will be distance to current cell + 1. The value for destination in the second queue will give you the path length.
2. When adding a neighbor in the queue, record his parent. So when you find the source you can reconstruct the path and count the number of steps.

Comment: The first one seems to be a good idea. I think I saw that in some graphs, where every step was called a "level" so we start at level 0 then we go to level 1 vertexes, then level 2 vertexes and so on. Thanks

Comment: @MindRoller, exactly. It should very easy to implement, just advance with both queues in parallel. The parent solution is harder to implement, and is probably an overkill if you don't need the actual path.

Comment: Well I made it :) Thanks. Actually solved the problem both ways, my own and the one @malioboro posted. I changed a pair to a pair that holds a pair and an int. And program is passing the current "level" to that int a pair holds.